# Logstash input jdbc is duplicating results

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana-4

I'm using logstash input jdbc plugin to read  two (or more) databases and send the data to elasticsearch, and using kibana 4 to vizualize these data.

This is my logstash config:

```
input {
  jdbc {
    type => "A"
    jdbc_driver_library => "C:\DEV\elasticsearch-1.7.1\plugins\elasticsearch-jdbc-1.7.1.0\lib\jtds-1.3.1.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "Java::net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://dev_data_base_server:1433/dbApp1;domain=CORPDOMAIN;useNTLMv2=true"
    jdbc_user => "user"
    jdbc_password => "pass"
    schedule => "5 * * * *"
    statement => "SELECT id, date, content, status from test_table"
  }

jdbc {
    type => "B"
    jdbc_driver_library => "C:\DEV\elasticsearch-1.7.1\plugins\elasticsearch-jdbc-1.7.1.0\lib\jtds-1.3.1.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "Java::net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://dev_data_base_server:1433/dbApp2;domain=CORPDOMAIN;useNTLMv2=true"
    jdbc_user => "user"
    jdbc_password => "pass"
    schedule => "5 * * * *"
    statement => "SELECT id, date, content, status from test_table"
  }
}
filter {

}
output {

    if [type] == "A" {
        elasticsearch {
            host => "localhost"
            protocol => http
            index => "logstash-servera-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        }    
    }
    if [type] == "B" {
        elasticsearch {
            host => "localhost"
            protocol => http
            index => "logstash-serverb-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        }    
    }

  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

The problem is that every time run the logstash, it starts to save all data that is already in elastic search.

After run with the where clause = date > '2015-09-10' I'd stoped the logstash and run again (with --debug) with the 'special parameter' :sql_last_date. After the logstash startup It starts to show this in the log:

```
←[36mExecuting JDBC query {:statement=>"SELECT \n\tSUBSTRING(R.RECEBEDOR, 1, 2)
AS 'DDD',\nCASE WHEN R.STATUS <>  'RCON' AND R.COD_RESPOSTA in (428,429,230,425,
430,427,418,422,415,424,214,433,435,207,426) THEN 'REGRA DE NEGÓCIO'  \n       W
HEN R.STATUS = 'RCON' THEN 'SUCESSO'\n\t   ELSE 'ERRO'\n   END AS 'TIPO_MENSAGEM
',\nAP.ALIAS as 'CANAL', R.ID_RECARGA, R.VALOR, R.STATUS, R.COD_RESPOSTA, R.DESC
_RESPOSTA, R.DT_RECARGA as '@timestamp', R.ID_CLIENTE, R.ID_DEPENDENTE, R.ID_APL
ICACAO, RECEBEDOR, R.ID_OPERADORA, R.TIPO_PRODUTO \n\nFROM RECARGA R (NOLOCK)\nJ
OIN APLICACAO AP ON R.ID_APLICACAO = AP.ID_APLICACAO \nwhere R.DT_RECARGA > :sql
_last_start\nORDER BY R.DT_RECARGA ASC", :parameters=>{:sql_last_start=>2015-09-
10 18:48:00 UTC}, :level=>:debug, :file=>"/DEV/logstash-1.5.4/vendor/bundle/jrub
y/1.9/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-1.0.0/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/jdbc.rb", :line=
>"107", :method=>"execute_statement"}←[0m
```

This time i ran with the 'real' statement that is:

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(R.RECEBEDOR, 1, 2) AS 'DDD',
CASE WHEN R.STATUS <>  'RCON' AND R.COD_RESPOSTA in (428,429,230,425,430,427,418,422,415,424,214,433,435,207,426) THEN 'REGRA DE NEGÓCIO'  
       WHEN R.STATUS = 'RCON' THEN 'SUCESSO'
       ELSE 'ERRO'
   END AS 'TIPO_MENSAGEM',
AP.ALIAS as 'CANAL', R.ID_RECARGA, R.VALOR, R.STATUS, R.COD_RESPOSTA, R.DESC_RESPOSTA, R.DT_RECARGA as '@timestamp', R.ID_CLIENTE, R.ID_DEPENDENTE, R.ID_APLICACAO, RECEBEDOR, R.ID_OPERADORA

FROM RECARGA R (NOLOCK)
JOIN APLICACAO AP ON R.ID_APLICACAO = AP.ID_APLICACAO 
where R.DT_RECARGA > :sql_last_start
ORDER BY R.DT_RECARGA ASC
```

Anyone knows how to solve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

`sql_last_start` is now `sql_last_value`[please check here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html#_predefined_parameters)
the special parameter `sql_last_start` is now renamed to `sql_last_value`  for better clarity as it is not only limited to datetime but may have other column type as well.
so now solution may be something like this

```
input {
jdbc {
     type => "A"
     jdbc_driver_library => "C:\DEV\elasticsearch-1.7.1\plugins\elasticsearch-  jdbc-1.7.1.0\lib\jtds-1.3.1.jar"
     jdbc_driver_class => "Java::net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
     jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://dev_data_base_server:1433/dbApp1;domain=CORPDOMAIN;useNTLMv2=true"
     jdbc_user => "user"
     jdbc_password => "pass"
     schedule => "5 * * * *"
     use_column_value => true
     tracking_column => date
     statement => "SELECT id, date, content, status from test_table WHERE date >:sql_last_value"
    #clean_run true means it will reset sql_last_value to zero or initial value if datatype is date(default is also false)
     clean_run =>false
   }
jdbc{
  #for type B....
  }
}
```

i have tested with sql Server DB

please run for first time with clean_run=>ture to avoid datatype error while in development we may have different datatype value stored in `sql_last_value` variable

Comment: Please provide the necessary information to answer the question on the site.

Comment: earlier i was just a comment as i was not having enough ranking to comment on above answer. now i wrote complete answer so it may help someone else..:)

Answer (score 4):

By default, the `jdbc` input will execute the configured SQL statement. In your case, your statement selects everything in `test_table`. You need to instruct your SQL statement to only load data from the last time the `jdbc` input ran by using the predefined [`sql_last_start`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html#_predefined_parameters) parameter in your SQL query.

```
input {
  jdbc {
    type => "A"
    jdbc_driver_library => "C:\DEV\elasticsearch-1.7.1\plugins\elasticsearch-jdbc-1.7.1.0\lib\jtds-1.3.1.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "Java::net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://dev_data_base_server:1433/dbApp1;domain=CORPDOMAIN;useNTLMv2=true"
    jdbc_user => "user"
    jdbc_password => "pass"
    schedule => "5 * * * *"
    statement => "SELECT id, date, content, status from test_table WHERE date > :sql_last_start"
  }

jdbc {
    type => "B"
    jdbc_driver_library => "C:\DEV\elasticsearch-1.7.1\plugins\elasticsearch-jdbc-1.7.1.0\lib\jtds-1.3.1.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "Java::net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://dev_data_base_server:1433/dbApp2;domain=CORPDOMAIN;useNTLMv2=true"
    jdbc_user => "user"
    jdbc_password => "pass"
    schedule => "5 * * * *"
    statement => "SELECT id, date, content, status from test_table WHERE date > :sql_last_start"
  }
}
```

Also if by any coincidence the same record is loaded twice from your DB and you don't want dups to be created in your ES server, you can also specify to use the record ID as the document ID in your `elasticsearch` output, that way the document will be updated in ES and not duplicated.

```
output {

    if [type] == "A" {
        elasticsearch {
            host => "localhost"
            protocol => http
            index => "logstash-servera-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
            document_id => "%{id}"       <--- same id as in DB
        }    
    }
    if [type] == "B" {
        elasticsearch {
            host => "localhost"
            protocol => http
            index => "logstash-serverb-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
            document_id => "%{id}"       <--- same id as in DB
        }    
    }

  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Comment: I've tried using this.

At the first time I used WHERE date > '2015-09-09'. The logstash got all data since yesterday until today 11:30am. Whe I ran at the second time (11:50), Logstash didn't got any data. And yes, have more data in the database.

Comment: The only thing that appears in the log is: 
Logstash startup completed
Logstash shutdown completed

Comment: Can you run logstash with `--debug` and provide some more output?

Comment: I'll add this output on the question.

Comment: In your output I see that `sql_last_start` was `2015-09-10 18:48:00 UTC`. Not sure if it's the issue but that's not really near 11:50am.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is happening. The data that is in elastic search seems to be right..

Comment: The data in ES is certainly right, but that's more an issue for what logstash retrieved or not from your DB, since you said it didn't get any data at 11:50am, which is normal since it was trying to get data updated after 18:48pm (i.e. in the future compared to the moment you ran logstash at 11:50am)