# Logstash in docker input jdbc plugin not picking up new rows

Tags: jdbc, elasticsearch, duplicates, logstash

I am trying to use the input jdbc plugin in a dockerized logstash container.

```
jdbc {
type => "logs"
jdbc_driver_library => "/opt/logstash/driver/ojdbc6.jar"
jdbc_driver_class => "Java::oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//<host>:<port>/<database>"
jdbc_user => "****"
jdbc_password => "****"
jdbc_fetch_size => 1000
schedule => "* * * * *" 
statement => "select ROWIDTONCHAR ( rowid ) AS rid_obj ,CONNECTION_ID, IPADDRESS,  START_DATE,  ELAPSED_TIME_MS,  GUI_EVENT_TYPE,  GUI_EVENT_NAME,  GUI_EVENT_PARAMS 
                 from table where start_date>:sql_last_start"
clean_run => false
record_last_run => true
last_run_metadata_path => "/opt/logstash/lastrun/.logstash_jdbc_last_run"
}
```

The metadata file is volume mapped as follows:

```
-v - /opt/logstash/lastrun/.logstash_jdbc_last_run:/opt/logstash/lastrun/.logstash_jdbc_last_run
```

Question:
The start_date field is a Date field not a time stamp field.  The sql_last_start is a timestamp field.  Is the comparison correct? The date in the table is not UTC.  I am not sure how to convert it to a format logstash understands.

I tried several ways of comparing including casting the date field to a timestamp field with UTC - none worked.

Every time I restart logstash goes over the entire file.  To prevent duplicates I used the solution from

[Logstash input jdbc is duplicating results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32503809/logstash-input-jdbc-is-duplicating-results)

Any input would be helpful.

Comment: Upon further inspection of the logs I found that the date is stored like this in the metadata file - 2015-12-18 17:14:00.236000000 Z  whereas in the logs it shows up as 2015-12-18 17:14:00 UTC.  I am not able to track down where the formatting is configured.

Comment: Has anyone run into this problem?  If so can you please share your solution?  Thanks

Comment: What is the format of the data in column `start_date`? If you give me some examples of what is in that column, we can solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I was also not able to find a way to format the timestamp the jdbc plugin stores in the last run metadata file.

So my solution was to instead re-format the datetime stamp stored in :sql_last_value to a value that could be compared to the time stamp in the database, using SQL functions to do the conversion. I was using mysql, and in mysql I converted the `2018-09-26 18:42:00.007000000 Z` timestamp I had in my last run metadata file to a unixtimestamp by doing this in my query:

`my_unixtimestamp_column > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(:sql_last_value, '%Y-%m-%d %T.%f000 Z'))`

I don't know whether you are using Oracle's TIMESTAMP or DATE data type in your `start_date` column, or what format you created for the data to be rendered in. So, I will base my answer on two guesses, and perhaps you can adapt your solution from there.

My first guess is that `start_date` is a TIMESTAMP data type, and that you formatted it as follows: `DD-MON-YY HH:MI:SSXFF` so your data ends up looking like this:

`01-JAN-03 02:00:00.000000 AM
01-JAN-04 04:21:55.891000 AM`
 
etc

So the task is to convert the timestamp stored in :sql_last_value to a format that the database engine can compare against its column values, in the sql query itself.

Here would be my possible solution, given the assumptions above:

```
statement => "select ROWIDTONCHAR ( rowid ) AS rid_obj ,CONNECTION_ID, IPADDRESS,  START_DATE,  ELAPSED_TIME_MS,  GUI_EVENT_TYPE,  GUI_EVENT_NAME,  GUI_EVENT_PARAMS 
             from table where start_date>TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(:sql_last_value, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH.MI.SSXFF Z')"
```

Since I don't have an Oracle system to test with and don't know the formats you are using, your solution will be a bit different, but this should point you in the right direction. The basic idea is to convert the `:sql_last_value` as captured in the last run metafile into the same date or timestamp format as you have stored in your column, so your comparison makes sense to the SQL engine you are using.

While it's theoretically possible to convert format of the values in your database column to the format of the date stored in the last run metadata, I think that would be much slower. Converting the static, stored date once for comparison against the rows in the table should be faster than converting every row in your table for comparison against the static string. HTH